# Passing in a column list and return multiple column values

Tags: python, pandas

**NOTE** StackOverflow does not recognize my multi-line code and complains that it needs 4 indents (provided), so I had to convert multi-line code to blockquotes.

First, I'm reading columns from a dataframe where I want to extract some of the column values.  In one case, I want to extract two column values in a list within a list and 1 just 1 column value (this is done).

The issue: I'm taking in a parameter that represents multiple several columns in a dataframe - in this case *my2Columns*:

*def myFunction(myFile,my2Columns)*

I read the file using pandas *df = pd.read_csv(myFile)* and from here need to extract 2 columns within this df:

*twoCols = df[['Col1', 'Col2']] ###hardcoing like this will work, but it's not dynamic*

Because the *my2Columns* parameter should be formatted like *['Col1', 'Col2']*, I thought creating the function and calling the function like this would work - but it doesn't and I get a key error:

> def myFunction(myFile,my2Columns)
> df = pd.read_csv(myFile)
> twoCols = df[my2Columns]
> return twoCols
>
> print(myFunction("myfile.csv","['Col1','Col2']"))
> #Same error:
> #print(myFunction("myfile.csv","'Col1','Col2'"))

Another technique I tried was converting it to a list after extraction:

> def myFunction(myFile,my2Columns)
> df = pd.read_csv(myFile)
> betweenConversion = df[my2Columns]
> twoCols = betweenConversion.tolist()
> return twoCols

Same key error here.  How do I pass in 2 columns for pandas to read from a file and store in 1 variable in the format of *[[Col1,Col2]* with the values such as *[[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]]*?

Comment: Use `print(myFunction("myfile.csv",['Col1','Col2']))`